# Joomla - MVC for component- multiple models for one view

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm developping a component with joomla 3 and I'm not really familiar with MVC framework.

The component will manage the registration of Users on my website.
There are 3 different types of Users.
A customized view must be displayed for each type -> one layout for each user (Usertype1,Usertype2,Usertype3).

Concerning the registration some methods are similars for all the userType but some are specific (like the function getForm() for example).

So I thought that the best option was to create one model for each Usertype and then to adapt the model loaded in the controller regarding to the layout in the URL:

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false){

        $view = $this->getView( 'registration');
        $layout = $this->input->get('layout');
        switch ($layout) {
                case "userType1":
                    $view->setModel( $this->getModel( 'userType1' ), true );
                    $view->display();
                    break;
                case "userType2":
                    $view->setModel( $this->getModel( 'userType2' ), true );
                    $view->display();
                    break;
                case "userType3":
                    $view->setModel( $this->getModel( 'userType3' ), true );
                    $view->display();
                    break;
            }   
        parent::display();
        return $this;
    }
```

this code does not work... Do you think that I have made the right choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for information the following code works perfectly:

In the view.html.php

```
  public function display($tpl = null)
  {
     $document = JFactory::getDocument();
     $app = JFactory::getApplication();

     $layout = $app->input->get('layout');
     switch ($layout) {
           case "UserType1":
              $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('userType1', 'ComponentModel');
              break;
           case "userType2":
              $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('userType2', 'ComponentModel');
              break;
           case "userType3":
              $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('userType3', 'ComponentModel');
              break;
     }
     $this->form = $model->getForm();

     //langage
     $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
     $this->tag = $lang->getTag();

     parent::display($tpl);
  }
```

My only concern is: I don't use the controller so I'm not sure that it's the cleanest way to work with **MVC approach**